# rendering multiple children of different types in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react you can do something like:

```
var Wrap = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>{ this.props.children }</div>;
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Wrap><h1>Hello word</h1></Wrap>;
    }
});
```

This allows you to pass in a component to another. But what if Wrap had another div that you could put content into. So consider the following:

```
var Wrap = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ul className="icons">
             // Another compoent should be passed here from App to render icons.
            </ul>
            { this.props.children }
          </div>
        );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Wrap><h1>Hello word</h1></Wrap>;
    }
});
```

In the above example you can see that not only do I want to pass in children of the `App` component but I also want to pass another component that is icons for the `ul` section. Is this possible?

If so, how?

Comment: Aren't these two different components? `<Icons />`, which returns the `<ul>`, and whatever goes inside `{ this.props.children}`. Then in `App` you can instantiate two different components rather than one. I think you'll continue to feel like you're fighting React if you pass components as props.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Pass the other component as prop, e.g.

   ```
   <Wrap icons={<Icons />}><h1>...</h1></Wrap>
   ```
2. Pass two children two `Wrap` and render each of them in the appropriate places, e.g.

   ```
   <Wrap>
     <Icons />
     <h1>...</h1>
   </Wrap>
   ```

Comment: how do you pass a component as a property? so if If I did `var Icons = React.createClass({});` would it be as you did `<Wrap icons={Icons} />` Also if I do the two children, how do I get the second children set? the first is `this.props.children` for the `<h1></h1>` but the second is?

Comment: You'd create the component like any other, e.g. `<Wrap icons={<Icons />} />`. `this.props.children` is actually either a single component or an array of components. There is a helper function available that will always return an array, but I can't remember it right now. If you pass two children, you can access the first one with `this.props.children[0]` and the second one with `this.props.children[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Higher order components to do this is cleaner than accessing children by index or looping imo.

```
const wrap = (Icons) => class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ul className="icons">
                <Icons {...this.props.iconProps} />
            </ul>
            { this.props.children }
          </div>
        );
    }
});

class AppIcons extends React.Component {
    render: function() {
        return <div />
    }
});

class App extends React.Component {
    render: function() {
        return <Wrap iconProps={this.props}><h1>Hello word</h1></Wrap>;
    }
});

const Wrap = wrap(AppIcons);


ReactDOM.render(App, domContainerNode)
```